# trying to access a value on another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to get a value from another function but it keeps displaying a NaN on my span tag  by the way my function getSummary() is put on onload in the body tag of the html

```
function calculate(){
    var coke = document.getElementById('drinks-coke').value;
    var royal = document.getElementById('drinks-royal').value;
    var sprite = document.getElementById('drinks-sprite').value;

    var drink1 = coke * 35;  
    var drink2 = royal * 35;  
    var drink3 = sprite * 35;  

    // "totaldrinks":
     var totald = document.getElementById("total-drinks").innerHTML = drink1+drink2+drink3; 
}

function calculateAddons(){
    var rice1 = document.getElementById('addons-rice').value;
    var sauce1 = document.getElementById('addons-sauce').value;
    var protein1 = document.getElementById('addons-protein').value;
    var vegies1= document.getElementById('addons-vegies').value;

    var addon1 = rice1 * 20;  
    var addon2 = sauce1 * 30;  
    var addon3 = protein1 * 70;  
    var addon4 = vegies1 * 50;  

    // "totaladdons": 
    var totala = document.getElementById("total-addons").innerHTML = addon1+addon2+addon3+addon4; 
}

function getSummary() {
    var riceData = document.getElementById("ricingbowlfinal").getAttribute("value");
    var deliveryData = document.getElementById("deliverycharge").getAttribute("value")
    var totalbill = parseInt(riceData) + parseInt(deliveryData);
    var totaldr = calculateAddons("totala")
    var totalad = calculate("totald")

    document.getElementById("summarys").innerHTML = totalbill + totaldr + totalad;
}
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from the first 2 functions.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy can u help me on that?

Comment: `return totald;`, `return totala;` - really not hard ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need a return value and to fix how your calling your functions. Your passing a string to your function when called but this is unnecessary.

```
function calculate(){
    //... 

    // "totaldrinks":
     var totald = document.getElementById("total-drinks").innerHTML = drink1+drink2+drink3; 
    return totald;
}

function getSummary() {
    var riceData = document.getElementById("ricingbowlfinal").getAttribute("value");
    //...

    var totalad = calculate()

    document.getElementById("summarys").innerHTML = totalbill + totaldr + totalad;
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need one value from (for example) calculate, change it to return the value:

```
function calculate(){
    var coke = document.getElementById('drinks-coke').value;
    var royal = document.getElementById('drinks-royal').value;
    var sprite = document.getElementById('drinks-sprite').value;

    var drink1 = coke * 35;  
    var drink2 = royal * 35;  
    var drink3 = sprite * 35;  

    // "totaldrinks":
     var totald = document.getElementById("total-drinks").innerHTML = drink1+drink2+drink3; 

   return totald;
}
```

calling code can then get that value with:

```
var total = calculate();
```

Answer (score 0):

return statement is missing from Calculate() and calculateAddons()
Here's your solution,

```
function calculate(){
    var coke = document.getElementById('drinks-coke').value;
    var royal = document.getElementById('drinks-royal').value;
    var sprite = document.getElementById('drinks-sprite').value;

    var drink1 = coke * 35;  
    var drink2 = royal * 35;  
    var drink3 = sprite * 35;  

    // "totaldrinks":
     var totald = document.getElementById("total-drinks").innerHTML = drink1+drink2+drink3; 
     return totald;
}

function calculateAddons(){
    var rice1 = document.getElementById('addons-rice').value;
    var sauce1 = document.getElementById('addons-sauce').value;
    var protein1 = document.getElementById('addons-protein').value;
    var vegies1= document.getElementById('addons-vegies').value;

    var addon1 = rice1 * 20;  
    var addon2 = sauce1 * 30;  
    var addon3 = protein1 * 70;  
    var addon4 = vegies1 * 50;  

    // "totaladdons": 
    var totala = document.getElementById("total-addons").innerHTML = addon1+addon2+addon3+addon4; 
     return totala;
}

function getSummary() {
    var riceData = document.getElementById("ricingbowlfinal").getAttribute("value");
    var deliveryData = document.getElementById("deliverycharge").getAttribute("value")
    var totalbill = parseInt(riceData) + parseInt(deliveryData);
    var totaldr = calculateAddons("totala")
    var totalad = calculate("totald")

    document.getElementById("summarys").innerHTML = totalbill + totaldr + totalad;
}
```